# PHP Inline URL Redirect?

Tags: php, url, redirect, header, onload

I was wondering if it was possible to make it where someone could just input the link:

and have it actually go to the real link when people visit.

This is what I have, but I don't know how to implement.

```
<?php
if( $_GET["k"] == "custom" ) header( "Location: {$_POST["first"]}_{$_POST["last"]}" );

$file = fopen( "link.php", "r" );

$data = fread( $file, filesize( "link.php" ) );


$first = $_GET["n"];
$last = fixN( $last );
$data = str_replace( "first", ucfirst( strtolower( $first ) ), $data );
$data = str_replace( "last", ucfirst( $last ), $data );


print  $data;

}
?>
```

On the page;

```
<BODY onLoad="first">
```

Even if you do the link, it wont only grab the last part.  Which is what I need it to redirect to.

---

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) AND filter_var(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),     FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="first">first</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the exact link http://LikeTreasure.com/google.com

I don't know what's wrong with it.

even if you specify a file type http://LikeTreasure.com/file.html

It always seems to send the entire url.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you are URL rewriting that to a PHP file...

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) AND filter_var(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

}
```

This will forward on the request if the `REQUEST_URI` environmental variable is set (it won't be in IIS) and it looks like a valid URL.